# Where with POST next insert in mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get a number from POST and check it against the `id` column in my table and get the name of this row. In the following code outputting with `print_r` works, but each of the values I stored in the table `order` just with the value `0`  (but in print_r values them not 0 and is same what i want) how can fix this problem? (i use codeigniter)

```
$query_cu    = $this->db->get_where('info', array(
    'id' => $this->input->post('number')
))->row();
$query_re    = $this->db->get_where('info', array(
    'id' => $this->input->post('recommend')
))->row();
$query_urf = $this->db->get_where('foreign', array(
    'id' => $this->input->post('name')
))->row();

$data  = array(
    'name' => $query_urf->name,
    'recommend' => $query_re->name,
    'number' => $query_cu->name       
);
$this->db->insert('order', $data);

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($data1);
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$data1`?

Comment: It was misspelled, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the structure of your 'order' table? If print_r($data) has the correct info I would double check that the columns have the proper format (text, varchar, etc) to handle the data.